# WPF - Combobox in header

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a datagrid like in the following.

```
        .............

         <DataGridTemplateColumn   >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="SomeTopic"/>
                            <ComboBox/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I want that column to have a combobox in its header. At the same time, I want all the rows in the datagrid to have comboboxes under the same column.

That's what I've written to achieve this. Everything is fine. But in the header what it shows is "System.Windows.Controls.Stackpanel".....It does not show the combobox in the header....not even the topic "sometopic".

where have I gone wrong ?

Can someone answer pls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.headertemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="SomeTopic"/>
                <ComboBox/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```